# Unable to get reset form using button in mvc form

Tags: forms, controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, reset

I'm trying to use MVC structure while building a sencha touch 2.3.1 app.
I have a form, and two buttons one for submission and other for resetting it.
I have added form view code in file [app/view/form1.js](http://pastebin.com/Jj16bGAj),
controller code to [app.controller.form1](http://pastebin.com/qbhhh0CD) and 
here's my [app.js](http://pastebin.com/GixqgT9i).

Can someone point out where I am wrong, and to a source where I can get a better understanding of how to use (I know what MVC is) MVC structure in Sencha. There documentation is a bit to simplified to include all this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is the getting of the form:

```
form1.reset();
```

You can get it with the auto generated getter method in the controller:

```
var form1 = this.getForm1();
```

And remove your double colon "::"

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Can you please explain how does
    var form1=this.getForm1(); 
works. I tried it in my [code](http://pastebin.com/vLSkbEq9) after following your advice, but I'm unable to get it working.

Comment: UPDATE 
got it working, typo error (was using this.getForm1() instead of this.getForm1orig() ), thanks a TON @Darin Kolev